# How to create "Script Generator Options" scripts in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, generate-scripts

I have a **SQL Server** database and whenever I want to make a backup of the database, first generate a `Drop and Create Script` of the DB. Because by this way I can make my database in every version of **SQL Server**. Regardless of the version and maintenance problems of SQL.

In the **Generate and Publish Scripts** window of **SQL Server** there is an **Advanced Scripting Option**, as shown below:

[image: Advanced Scripting Options]

Now, I would like a script from this window to reproduce script generator **advanced options**. In the other words, I want a script to make script generator of my database by my selected **Advanced Options**.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SQL Server Profiler to retrieve executing sqls in the specified instance.

[[image: How to see executing batch sqls in the specified instance][1]]

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this [How to generate SQL Table Script through query](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/305072/how-to-generate-sql-table-scripts-through-query-in)

Is this what you want?

```
declare @table varchar(100)
set @table = 'MyTable' -- set table name here
declare @sql table(s varchar(1000), id int identity)

-- create statement
insert into  @sql(s) values ('create table [' + @table + '] (')

-- column list
insert into @sql(s)
select 
    '  ['+column_name+'] ' + 
    data_type + coalesce('('+cast(character_maximum_length as varchar)+')','') + ' ' +
    case when exists ( 
        select id from syscolumns
        where object_name(id)=@table
        and name=column_name
        and columnproperty(id,name,'IsIdentity') = 1 
    ) then
        'IDENTITY(' + 
        cast(ident_seed(@table) as varchar) + ',' + 
        cast(ident_incr(@table) as varchar) + ')'
    else ''
    end + ' ' +
    ( case when IS_NULLABLE = 'No' then 'NOT ' else '' end ) + 'NULL ' + 
    coalesce('DEFAULT '+COLUMN_DEFAULT,'') + ','

 from information_schema.columns where table_name = @table
 order by ordinal_position

-- primary key
declare @pkname varchar(100)
select @pkname = constraint_name from information_schema.table_constraints
where table_name = @table and constraint_type='PRIMARY KEY'

if ( @pkname is not null ) begin
    insert into @sql(s) values('  PRIMARY KEY (')
    insert into @sql(s)
        select '   ['+COLUMN_NAME+'],' from information_schema.key_column_usage
        where constraint_name = @pkname
        order by ordinal_position
    -- remove trailing comma
    update @sql set s=left(s,len(s)-1) where id=@@identity
    insert into @sql(s) values ('  )')
end
else begin
    -- remove trailing comma
    update @sql set s=left(s,len(s)-1) where id=@@identity
end

-- closing bracket
insert into @sql(s) values( ')' )

-- result!
select s from @sql order by id
```

Comment: this is a way to create script, but my question is about create a advanced options script in Stable state of sql server. thanks for answer +1